# 2 projects and references between them

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, reference, n-tier-architecture

I have main project and second with several `UserControls`.
I use in main project this usercontrols, and in `UserControls` is a need to use some classes (responsible for `BusinessLogic` and `DataAccessLayer`) from main project.

How to connect both projects? Now it creates circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible aproaches involves binding your user controls to specifications of your services instead of implementations.

Technically, this means that you have another library, shared between your main project and your control library which contains your specifications:

```
public interface IBusinessLogic
{
   void DoSomething();
}
```

Then, in your user control library you code against interfaces, allowing implementations to be injected:

```
public MyControl : UserControl
{
   private IBusinessLogic _logic;
   public MyControl( IBusinessLogic logic )
   {
      this._logic = logic;
   } 
   // use the _logic
}
```

and in your main module you provide an implementation of your service and inject it to your controls:

```
public MyBusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic { }

MyControl control = new MyControl( new MyBusinessLogic() ); // inject the implementation
```

Comment: Technically the interfaces could go in the UserControls assembly, as main has a reference to this. Although I largely agree with programming against an interface as a general style, I am undecided as to whether I would use it to get around a circular dependency (it *feels* like a code smell, but I'm on the fence at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Do not create `BusinessLogic` and `DataAccessLayer` insider your main project.
Create each one in its own project, and reference them from your main project.

**Note:** Better off - `DataAccessLayer` should only be referenced from `BusinessLogic` and your main project should only reference `BusinessLogic`.

But this is only a short answer to your problem in a nutshell. I recommend you to search here more about [3-tier architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=3%20tier).

Comment: So where? How do you propose divide this projects?

Answer (score 0):

Put your Business Logic and Data Access Layer in a third project, maybe call it 'Common'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take the shared logic out of both projects and put it into a third project.

For instance: If you have logic in your Main project that the user controls also needs - you need to extract that logic into a separate project and reference that from both projects.